# How to defocus dropdown in IE? (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

So I have a blank page for example with a select-option dropdown (clasic) in IE. I click on it change value (or right click) to make it blue (focused).

[image]

Now if you go with mouse over it and start to scroll => you will see that value is changing. In Chrome doesn't happened this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to defocus dropdown in IE? (AngularJS) Now if you go with mouse
>   over it and start to scroll => you will see that value is changing. In
>   Chrome doesn't happened this!

From your description, I think you want to prevent to use the scrolling the mouse method to change the selected value. If that is the case, you could refer to the following code to return false in the onmousewheel event:

```
<select ng-model="selectedName" onmousewheel="return false;" ng-options="x for x in names">
</select>
```